# Reaction on the message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

My code

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  emoji = ''
  message = message.id
  await bot.add_reaction(message, emoji)
```

---

**Error in console**

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 31, in on_message
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

As the python interpreter helpfully points out, your `Bot` object doesn't have the function `add_reaction()`. Instead, it's available to the [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) object:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  emoji = ''
  await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

You can look at their FAQ for more help: ["How do I add a reaction to a message?"](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message)